# SUMIFS with blanks in range criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have the following Excel spreadsheet (simplified)

[image]

This spreadsheet is monthly shared among many collaborators (one for each department who are allowed to insert a new row for the department where they belong, the items sold along with the quantity.

In this configuration, the A column (DEPT) has some blanks that my users won't fill with the department value.

I would like to perform a SUMIFS to determine, for example, how many ITEM_A has been sold

I already tried

```
=SUMIFS(C1:C8;A1:A8;"DEPT_A";B1:B8;"ITEM_A")
```

but, due to blanks, this doesn't work. The spreadsheet contains so many rows I can't even think of manually filling the blanks. I tried some formula to do that ("if cell is blank use above value), but, as I said, when a user inserts a new row the formula doesn't apply.

If there a way to tell Excel to use, if blank, the upper value it finds in the column?

Comment: Would a way to fill in column A rapidly be acceptable?

Comment: A less breakable system is to have the users insert Dept, Item and Count into a structured table and then base a pivot table on that structured table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula you could use:

[image]

Formula in `H2`:

```
=SUMIF(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F2,A:A,0)):INDEX(B:B,IF(MATCH(F2,A:A,0)=LARGE((ISTEXT(A1:A9))*ROW(A1:A9),1),COUNTA(B:B),SMALL(IF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F2,A:A,0)+1):A9<>"",ROW(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F2,A:A,0)+1):A9),""),1)-1)),G2,INDEX(C:C,MATCH(F2,A:A,0)):INDEX(C:C,IF(MATCH(F2,A:A,0)=LARGE((ISTEXT(A1:A9))*ROW(A1:A9),1),COUNTA(B:B),SMALL(IF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F2,A:A,0)+1):A9<>"",ROW(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F2,A:A,0)+1):A9),""),1)-1)))
```

It's an array formula and should be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

This was quite a struggle :S....

You can, if you want to make it more dynamic when people start adding rows etc. Swap all the A9 references out for INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(B:B))